# How to solve this limit? (Use of cube difference identity and rationalization?)

Tags: limits

[image: The limit]

I've got the answer by converting the limit to $(x^3-8x^2)^{1/3}-x+1$ and then applying a "rationalizing" factor using the identity $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$ to get it in fractional form. From here, I divide the top and bottom of the fraction by $x^2$ to get the answer. However, this was algebraically tedious and I was wondering if anyone could think of a better, more elegant way.

Comment: One does not "solve" a limit; one *finds* a limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the finite constant $+1$ out. Then by the conjugate trinomial trick, the numerator becomes $x^2(x-8)-x^3=-8x^2$, and there will be three terms (not cancelling) of order $x^2$ in the denominator plus lower powers.

Hence $-\dfrac83+1$.

Tedious ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that, as $\displaystyle x \to \infty$,
\begin{align}
x^{2/3}\left(x - 8\right)^{1/3}
& = x\left(1 - {8 \over x}\right)^{1/3}
\sim x\left[1 + {1 \over 3}\left(-\,{8 \over x}\right)
+ {1/3\left(1/3-1\right) \over 2}\left(-\,{8 \over x}\right)^{2}\right]
\\[5mm] & =
x - {8 \over 3} - {64 \over 9x}
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
x^{2/3}\left(x - 8\right)^{1/3} - x + 1 &
\sim \color{red}{\large-\,{5 \over 3}} - {64/9 \over x}\qquad\mbox{as}\quad x \to \infty
\end{align}